# Cancel previous click on Google Analytics Events

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics

Is there any way to cancel the previous click on Google Events ?

Below is how my function to record click look like:

```
    <script>

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                scroll_events.bind_events( {
                    universal: 1,
                    gtm:0,

                    scroll_elements: [],
                    click_elements: [{'select':'.button-container-desktopa','category':'Click','action':{'select':'#q1a1','category':'Quiz','action':'Q1 Answer 1','label':'q1_a1','bounce':'true','evalue':''},{'select':'#q1a2','category':'Quiz','action':'Q1 Answer 2','label':'q1_a2','bounce':'true','evalue':''},{'select':'#q1a3','category':'Quiz','action':'Q1 Answer 3','label':'q1_a3','bounce':'true','evalue':''},{'select':'.next.1','category':'Quiz','action':'Answer Question One','label':'quizOne','bounce':'true','evalue':''},}],
                });
            });

</script>
```

Basically as you can see I'm trying to record which answer user have click in a test. but at the moment if the user click on answer 1, then answer 2, it will record the 2 events. I'm looking to only record the last answer click by the user.

Any guidance will be wonderfull !

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried firing the event on unload?  Something such as:

```html
$( window ).unload(function() {
  // fire event here
});
```